# Exclude elements from jQuery object

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me if there is some "simple way" to get complement set of elements in jQuery? I have following piece of code...

```
var parent = $('.parent-box'),
    inner = parent.find('.inner-box'); 

parent = parent - inner; // pseudocode - I want all elements except these in "inner"
```

...and I'd like to exclude "inner" from "parent". filter() or not() methods don't work for me in this case.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Ok, maybe in other words :) . I wrote simple "accordion" script:

http://jsfiddle.net/e2a6tr2f/1/

As you can see, one accordion (inner-box) is inside other accordion (parent-box) which causes that when "accord-btn" is clicked inside "inner-box", all .accord-block(s) collapse. 
I'd like to separate .accord-btn(s) and .accord-block(s) from "inner-box", so they collapse/expand only in "inner-box". So I thought, that I could write sth like this:

```
accordions.each(function () {
    var this_accordion = $(this),
        inner = this_accordion.find('.inner-box');

        if(inner.length > 0) {
            this_accordion = this_accordion - inner; // complement set
        }

    var headers = this_accordion.find('.accord-btn'),
        blocks = this_accordion.find('.accord-block');

    headers.each(function () {
       //
    });
});}
```

...and exclude "inner" accordion click events from "main" accordion.

Comment: We need to see your HTML to help you, although it sounds like you need the `not()` method; http://api.jquery.com/not

Comment: What do you want to do with that selection? Do you need its content or something else?

Comment: You want all `.parent-box` elements except those that have an `.inner-box` ancestor element? Without your HTML it's hard, if not impossible, to offer a solution without guessing. Which makes the question both unclear, too broad and off-topic (given that you don't include enough code to replicate your problem). Please, post enough sample HTML and clearly show the elements you want to find and those you do not. Regarding the inclusion of code, please see the "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" guidelines.

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Please check it. Does it correspond your needs?

Comment: Yes, it does :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this approach is match your needs? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tpf3wa0/)

`var childsExceptInnerBox = parent.children().not(".inner-box");`

**Update**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2a6tr2f/2/)

```
$(function () {
    var accordions = $(".accordion");
    accordions.each(function () {
        $(".accord-btn").on("click", function () {
            $(".accord-btn").removeClass("expanded");
            var accordBtn = $(this);
            accordBtn.addClass("expanded");
            if (!accordBtn.parents(".accordion").hasClass("inner-box")) {
                $(".accord-block").stop().hide("fast");
            }
            accordBtn.next(".accord-block").stop().show("fast");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This will work only if `.inner-box` are children or `.parent-box`.

Comment: @skobaljic `inner = parent.find('.inner-box');` means that he wants to remove child. Or not?

Comment: No, [find method](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will search for any element, not only direct children.

Comment: @skobaljic Well, `var childsExceptInnerBox = $(".parent-box").find("*").not(".inner-box");` should help.

Comment: No mate, each `.inner-box` may have children and those would be selected with the code you provided above. The question is not clear enough, please wait OP to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
$("*").each(function() { 
     if($(this).hasClass('inner-box')){
            //do nothing
     }
     else{
           //elements you want
      alert($(this).val());
     }
 });
```